# Screen Capture API via getDisplayMedia results in poor quality

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am not aware if this is a well justified and intentional. I've Googled around and the docs are incredibly scant, I'm aware there is `bitrate` but I've played around with all sorts of values and still the result is the same. The text is barely legible.

[image: It's this bad]

```js
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video: {width: {ideal: 4096}, height: {ideal: 2160}, frameRate: 30}, audio: true});

const options = {
   // audioBitsPerSecond: 128000,
      videoBitsPerSecond: 14000000 /* 14,000Kbps bitrate should be enough for HD video */
};
```

Is it completely impossible to obtain HD screen recording through this?

`getConstraints()` gives me: `{"aspectRatio":1.7777777777777777,"cursor":"always","deviceId":"window:18067:0","displaySurface":"window","frameRate":30,"height":1080,"logicalSurface":true,"resizeMode":"crop-and-scale","width":1920}` before I provide the options.

Thanks.

Comment: It's possible that the stream is fine, but you're rendering it incorrectly; how are you rendering the stream for display?

Comment: Also, what do you see listed in the video track's `getConstraints()`?

Comment: I just find-out that the `videoBitsPerSecond` that you pass into `MediaRecorder` are moot if the source stream (getom `getUserMedia` are at a lower bitrate - sop you need to check the (implicit) constraints in/on `getUserMedia` - so that's _before_ you construct your `options` for the `MediaRecorder`.

Comment: @Dai In the constraints I don't see max bitrate or quality permitted.

Comment: @Dai It's unlikely, I am both showing it inside `<video>` in the HTML and then downloading it as well and they are both bad. Roughly the same as the official example on the MDN for this. Even there the quality is bad.